# Find SQL query errors without executing the SQL query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to find the SQL query errors without executing the query in SQL server?

For example,

```
Use TestDB
Select * from Employee1
```

Consider TestDB doesn’t contain any table named “Employee1”. In this case, while we running this query, we will get the “**Invalid object name Employee1**” SQL error.

My question is that, after writing the query, is there any better approach to find these errors without executing?

I got a comment from my colleague is that use the sp_describe_first_result_set System stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2012 and above you can use the sp that your colleague has mentioned.

If you use 2008 R2 and less then use

```
SET FMTONLY  ON;
Select * from MyTabl;
SET FMTONLY  OFF;
```

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'MyTabl'.

This will execute the query but not process any data. NOEXEC only parses the query so any objects that don't exist will not be flagged. NOEXEC checks syntax only. So what you want is either sp_describe_first_result_set or FMTONLY.

Alternatively if you have a select then you can also append to your where 1=2. For example

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTabl
WHERE 1=2
```

which gives them same result
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'MyTabl'